# fetching and looping the fb newsfeed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to design a news feed with fully functioning likes/Unlike ,share and commenting,and of course fetching recent posts from users newfeed.Now here is the thing,I want to check whether a user has liked a post (type is video, photo, link or status).If a user has liked the post already, then show unlike button, if a user has not liked, show like button.

FILES:

[test.php](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1bHVDQnppeFV0SjQ/edit?usp=sharing)

THE PROBLEM IS that whenever i remove the following code(Which gets the user_likes for checking if user has liked the post or not)from the file:

```
$fql = 'SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id =' . "$ids";
        $ret = $facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql,
        ));

        $checklike = $ret['data']['like_info']['user_likes'];
```

the program will fetch only one post from newsfeed or sometimes not at all.Basically ,Any api calls i make inside the loop(except one for comment),it will affect the fetching data from newfeed.please tell me if there is any problem

Comment: This site should be called HumanDebuggerOverflow. We don't know if there's a problem, because you haven't explained the error properly. What error, codes(if any)?

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the above code from your script just like this, since just after this code you are accessing `$checklike` which would create the error.